# jquery scrolltop() returns value of previous scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, scrolltop

I am using jquery function `element.scrollTop()` to get the current scroll position of the page using following line:

```
var currentScrollPosition=  $('html').scrollTop() || $('body').scrollTop();
```

But it always return a value of previous scroll position. Please check the code below (which is same as is [in here](https://jsfiddle.net/5r74m54x/1/)). 
As you can try yourself and see in the code, after each tiny scroll, we get following series of values:

**(1: when code is first run and no move is made yet)**

delta:0

cumulativeDelta:0

functionCallCount:0

currentScrollPosition:0

*(delta gives how much is scrolled, cumulativeDelta gives total amount of scroll, functionCallCount is how many times you scrolled and currentScrollPosition is value returned by scrolltop() )*

**(2: when scrolled a little)**

delta:-120

cumulativeDelta:-120

functionCallCount:1

currentScrollPosition:0

*(note here, currentScrollPosition is still not updated)*

**(3: when scrolled a little further)**

delta:-120

cumulativeDelta:-240

functionCallCount:2

currentScrollPosition:90.90908893868948

*(here, cumulativeDelta, which is addition of total scroll made so far, is doubled and currentScrollPosition is updated for the first time)*

**(4: when scrolled a little more)**

delta:-120

cumulativeDelta:-360

functionCallCount:3

currentScrollPosition:181.81817787737896

*(now, cumulativeDelta is tripled while currentScrollPosition is doubled. Hence, this is value after two scrolls but is updated adter 3 scrolls)*

I apologize for long question, but would have been difficult to ask otherwise. I would like to know why is this happening and if I should use this function some other way there are any alternative to this function.

```js
document.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler);
var cumulativeDelta = 0,
  functionCallCount = 0;

function MouseWheelHandler(e) {
  e = window.event || e; // 'event' with old IE support
  var delta = e.wheelDelta || -e.detail; // get delta value

  cumulativeDelta += delta;
  functionCallCount += 1;
  currentScrollPosition = $('html').scrollTop() || $('body').scrollTop();

  document.getElementById("info1").innerHTML = "delta:" + delta;
  document.getElementById("info2").innerHTML = "cumulativeDelta:" + cumulativeDelta;
  document.getElementById("info3").innerHTML = "functionCallCount:" + functionCallCount;
  document.getElementById("info4").innerHTML = "currentScrollPosition:" + currentScrollPosition;

}
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
  border: solid red 3px;
}
.normalPart {
  border: solid green 2px;
  height: 900px;
}
.stationary {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stationary">
  <div id="info1"></div>
  <div id="info2"></div>
  <div id="info3"></div>
  <div id="info4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the mousewheel event fires when the mousewheel movement starts. You are reading the `scrollTop` at the point *before* the update has happened. You need to use a timer to get the `scrollTop` *after* the mouse wheel scroll has finished. Try this:

```js
document.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler);
var cumulativeDelta = 0,
    functionCallCount = 0,
    currentScrollPosition = 0;

function MouseWheelHandler(e) {
    e = window.event || e; // 'event' with old IE support
    var delta = e.wheelDelta || -e.detail; // get delta value

    cumulativeDelta += delta;
    functionCallCount += 1;

    setTimeout(function() {
        currentScrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
        document.getElementById("info4").innerHTML = "currentScrollPosition:" + currentScrollPosition;
    }, 200); // update currentScrollPos 200ms after event fires

    document.getElementById("info1").innerHTML = "delta:" + delta;
    document.getElementById("info2").innerHTML = "cumulativeDelta:" + cumulativeDelta;
    document.getElementById("info3").innerHTML = "functionCallCount:" + functionCallCount;
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
  border: solid red 3px;
}
.normalPart {
  border: solid green 2px;
  height: 900px;
}
.stationary {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stationary">
  <div id="info1"></div>
  <div id="info2"></div>
  <div id="info3"></div>
  <div id="info4"></div>
</div>
```

Alternatively you could read the `currentScrollTop` position directly on the scroll event of the window as that will always be in sync with its current position.

Comment: That's really awesome! Exactly what I wanted :) ... also with explaination.
Thanks for quick and precise reply .. will try and implement this.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: just would like to know, any particular reason to choose 200ms? 
I tried with lesser time, and was getting different values for currentScrollPosition. Eg. 50ms delay resulted in around 0.09 while 100ms in 0.6. Actual result should be 0.90-0.95. 

So it seems it takes about 200ms for the scroll process to finish. 

Actually, I want to run further code after this calculation. I want that after a particular scroll value, mousewheel scroll should result in horizontal scrolling, and some other value, resume normal scrolling. But adding delay won't make it real time.

can you suggest something ?

Comment: If you lower the delay the animation of the scroll will still be in progress, hence you see different values. I used 200ms as it seemed the lowest yet most reliable time that the transition had ended. If you want to check the actual scroll position in real time, hook to the `scroll` event of the window directly.

Comment: yupp .. https://jsfiddle.net/5r74m54x/2/ this simplifies stuffs greatly .. Thanks a lot again :) .. just curious .. how does browser works differently in this approach ??

Answer (score 1):

I would listen for the `scroll` event instead of `wheel`. Scroll activates after the `scrollTop` value has been updated.

`target.onscroll = functionRef`

Great example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onscroll)