# which on is indicated by jQuery.scrollTop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have confuse about a value returned from `jQuery.scrollTop()`.

which node indicates `jQuery.scrollTop()`?
the red one or green?

[image: the screen shot]

Comment: Please see below link for Jquery Scrolltop() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36518372/jquery-scrolltop-returns-value-of-previous-scroll-position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in short, thats green, but thats not realy the answer

read this from jquery site

> The vertical scroll position is the same as the number of pixels that
>   are hidden from view above the scrollable area. If the scroll bar is
>   at the very top, or if the element is not scrollable, this number will
>   be 0.

[image]

Comment: So its not about the scrollbar object (in visual) right?

Comment: @BarOKurniawan  yup, its exactly height of hidden area above the visible content in pixels